# Defining a number of columns different to 1 in a multicolumn

Tags: tables, arrays, multicolumn

I know how to use multicolumn. For example, I may produce the following scheme

```
-------------
|     A     |
-------------
|     B     |
-------------
| C | D | E |
-------------
```

with

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
 \multicolumn 3{|c|}{A}\\\hline
 \multicolumn 3{|c|}{B}\\\hline
 C & D & E\\\hline
\end{array}
```

Now, what I want to produce is the following, and that I do not know how:

```
-------------
|     A     |
-------------
| B | C | D |
-------------
| E | F | G |
-------------
|  H  |  I  |
-------------
|  J  |  K  |
-------------
```

Any ideas? I tried with `\multicolumn 3{|c|c|}{Text}` but did not work.

Comment: `multicol` package? I see the `\multicolumn` command there

Comment: One fairly awful solution is to have 6 columns and make each of `B`, ...,``G` span 2 columns and `H`,...,`K` span 3 columns. Using the array package you can probably streamline this...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: My mistake, I tough the `\multicolumn` command was part of the `multicol` package.

Comment: I just tested my idea and, weirdly, it doesn't work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384814/wierd-multicolumn-spacing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution based on `tabularx` so you don't have to specify whatever width except the total width of the table: roughly speaking, the  `\multicolumn{1.5}...` is obtained nesting a `tabularx{X|X}`  of the relevant width inside a `\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A} \\
  \hline
  B & C & D \\
  \hline
  E & F & G \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|@{}c@{}|}{\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth}[t] {>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    H & I \\
    \hline
    J & K
  \end{tabularx}} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to highlight a bit more the fact that the final two rows involve constructing a nested `tabularx` environment.

Comment: @Mico: you're right. I'm not sure to be very clear, but 'tis done, my lord!

Comment: I think this is the more elegant solution. I actually did something similar by nesting arrays, but the lines in the second array do not touch the borders, but it does with your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that guarantees that the column widths will be in a ratio of 2:3:6. The main length parameter to choose is `\mylen`. In the example below, it's set to `1cm`; feel free to choose a different value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}     % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for "\Centering" macro

% Create a centered version of "p" column type:
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

% Basic length variable: "\mylen"
\newlength\mylen 
\setlength\mylen{1cm} % <-- set length to suit your needs

\newlength\lengtha \setlength\lengtha{2\mylen}
\newlength\lengthb \setlength\lengthb{3\mylen}

%% Four user macros: \mcaa, \mcab, \mcba, \mcbb. 
%% Use \mcaa and \mcba for the *first* cell in a given row; 
%% use \mcab and \mcbb for the remaining cells in a row.
\newcommand\mcaa[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|C{\lengtha}|}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcab[1]{\multicolumn{2}{ C{\lengtha}|}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcba[1]{\multicolumn{3}{|C{\lengthb}|}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcbb[1]{\multicolumn{3}{ C{\lengthb}|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{C{\mylen}}}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{A} \\        % row with single, very wide cell
\hline
\mcaa{B} & \mcab{C} & \mcab{D} \\ % row with 3 cells
\hline
\mcaa{E} & \mcab{F} & \mcab{G} \\ % row with 3 cells
\hline
\mcba{H} & \mcbb{I} \\            % row with 2 cells
\hline
\mcba{J} & \mcbb{K} \\            % row with 2 cells
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. This a better answer. [Answers should not be accepted so fast](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/should-we-wait-a-bit-before-accepting-answers). Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No need. I accepted another answer instead of yours. Sorry for accepting that fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an array with 4 columns and set the length of them with the self defined `columntype` `C`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\(
\begin{array}{|*4{C{10mm}|}}\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|C{40mm}|}{A}\\ \hline
    B & \multicolumn{2}{|C{13mm}|}{C} & D\\ \hline
    E & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{F} & G\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C{20mm}}{H} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{I}\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{J} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{K}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some of the cell contents are typeset in text mode, whereas others are typeset in math mode. Is this deliberate? Also, the letter "A" does not appear to be centered over the letters "C" and "F".